# Infinite Cardinal Addition Without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

In the book 'Introduction to Set Theory' by Hrbacek and Jech, cardinal addition is defined as

$$\sum_{i \in I}{\kappa_i}=\left|\bigcup_{i \in I}{A_i} \right|$$

where $|A_i|=k_i$ for all $i \in I$ and $\langle A_i\mid i \in I\rangle$ is a system of mutually disjoint sets.

The author stated that: Without the  Axiom of Choice, there may exists two system $\langle A_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\rangle$, $\langle A^{\prime}_n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\rangle$ of mutually disjoint sets such that each $A_n$ and each $A^{\prime}_n$ has two elements, but $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty{A_n}$ is not equipotent to $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty{A^{\prime}_n}$.

I try to construct such example but I fail to do so. I tried the set of even natural numbers and natural numbers but they have the same cardinality after infinite union.

Comment: You can't construct such an example without using some extra set-theoretic principles.

Comment: May I know what are the needed extra set-theoretic principle?

Comment: It is consistent with ZF that $\Bbb{R}$ is countable union of countable subsets of $\Bbb{R}$. See [the related thread in MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/100717/48041)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't *construct* such example. The fact that it is only consistent and not provable is exactly the issue here. Not only you can't construct one, you can't *prove* that one exists when the axiom of choice fails.

These remarks, at the introductory level, are meant to guide the reader and suggest that a choice-free proof cannot be found. This is used to both (1) reassure the reader when they can't think of a choice free argument; and (2) to bring to the attention of the reader that even if they think that they evaded the axiom of choice, they have not.

[Cardinality of union of pairwise disjoint elements needs choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698647/cardinality-of-union-of-pairwise-disjoint-elements-needs-choice/) and [axiom of choice: cardinality of general disjoint union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89194/axiom-of-choice-cardinality-of-general-disjoint-union) have more information about situations where this happens.